# How to use thenCallRealMethod in Mockito Scala test cases for testing trait method?

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I have a trait with functions implemented in it. I want to mock the methods of trait and for a method, I want to use `thenCallRealMethod`. I am using Mockito Framework in Scala. But when I try to use `thenCallRealMethod` for a method, then I get the following error :

> Cannot call abstract real method on java object!
> Calling real methods is only possible when mocking non abstract method.
> //correct example:
> when(mockOfConcreteClass.nonAbstractMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();
> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:

Here is my Code :

```
trait X{
  def solve() : String = "solve"
  def solve2() : String = "solve2"
}
class XTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MockitoSugar{
    "test" can "test methods in trait" in{
          val mockedX = mock[X]
          when(mockedX.solve()) thenCallRealMethod()//this line throws the error
    }
}
```

This code throws the error metioned. One approach is using a class which can extend the trait, but I don't want to extend the trait and looking for another approach.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, seems to work fine for me. Having said that, calling real methods on mocks is usually a sign of badly designed class structure (violating single responsibility principle), so, you may want to reconsider wanting to do that in the first place.

Comment: @Dima, "calling real methods on mocks is usually a sign of badly designed class structure", then why is thenCallRealMethod a part of mock functionality itself in first place?

Comment: Same reason there was a `goto` statement in java (until 1.6 if I am not mistaken), or `return` or `throw` in scala, I guess :) I am not quite sure why exactly people put features into languages and libraries that enable use of anti-patterns, just know that they sometimes do (thus the term "anti-pattern" :)). Perhaps, it's because nobody thought about it being bad at the start, and by the time they realized it, it was too late to remove, because it is being used to widely? I dunno.

Comment: In this case, maybe, it is even simpler: this is a unit testing library. So, if it didn't provide a tool helping people test badly designed classes, it would hardly make anything better :)

Comment: @Dima, Actually my usecase is to test a `method` in a class. But this method depends upon `another method` in same class. So, I have to mock when `another method` is called by `method`. Hence, I mock the class and use thenCallRealMethod on `method` and mock the return value of `another method`.

Comment: "this method depends upon another method in same class." –– right. That's  exactly what Single Responsibility Principle says you should not do.

Comment: BTW, if you are going to use anti-patterns anyway, there's a better one for your use case :) You might want to use `spy[X]` instead of `mock[X]`: spies are like mocks, but everything already defaults to calling actual methods, so you don't have to specify it explicitly, just stub out the ones you want to stub.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be on Java 17? I just upgraded my jdk and these came up all over the place (was on 11 before)

Answer (score 0):

(I encountered this issue while upgrading scala 2.13 code from JDK 11 to JDK 17)

As you say in your comment you're actually wanting a base implementation in solve that calls another extended method:

```
trait X{
  def solve() : String = "solution: " + solve2()
  def solve2() : String
}
```

(please update your question with some code similar to your actual problem...)

As @Dima said, this violates SRP. So, make a method with the correct responsibility

```
object X {
  def solve(x: X) : String = "solution: " + x.solve2()
}
```

and test this. Since you probably want to have fluent calls (and method discoverability), delegate from the trait:

```
trait X{
  def solve() : String = X.solve(this)
  def solve2() : String
}
```

For me, this falls into the "too simple to test" category and allows you to keep your other code as-is, while keeping logic separate for testing etc.